# Pokemon Go Routes Not Working

Tags: pokemon-go

I have one account that the routes do not appear on. But when I go into another account the routes are there. When I click on the routes map it says "There are no routes nearby", even when I am standing right on one. There could be two things I think it could be.  The account could be under a birthday of a 17 year old, or that it was banned for a week once. But I have no clue to what else it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Niantic Help](https://niantic.helpshift.com/hc/en/6-pokemon-go/faq/4184-routes-faq), this could be one of two things:

1. Make sure the account is at least level 5.

   > *In order to be able to follow a Route, you must first reach Level 5*
2. For child accounts, make sure the account has the appropriate settings enabled in either *Niantic Kids* or *Pokemon Trainer Club*, whichever is applicable

   > Additionally, if you login with a child account (via Niantic Kids or Pokémon Trainer Club), check the Friends and related features settings in the Parent Portal.